# TEST pin of 8086

Tags: x86-16, microprocessors

According to some online lectures:

> 8086 will enter a wait state after execution of the WAIT instruction and will resume execution only when the () is made low by an active hardware.

Then, what is the use of TEST pin in the minimum mode of 8086 microprocessor? Why it is not one of maximum mode specific pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TEST input and the WAIT instruction are used to poll for an external event. This polling capability can be useful in any processor mode. Thus the pin is not specific to maximum mode.

In fact, this limited form of polling is most often useful in very small systems, so its inclusion in minimum mode makes a great deal of sense.

Larger systems tend to use interrupts more for this sort of thing.